# Woocommerce - How to get products which have a sale between two percents?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce - How to get products which have a sale between two percents, Let's say between 20% to 40%.

I tried using meta query but it is not comparing percentage rage. 
My Code :

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php

        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'meta_query'     => array(
                    'relation' => 'BETWEEN',
                    array( // Simple products type
                        'key'           => '_sale_price',
                        'value'         => 0,
                        'compare'       => '>',
                        'type'          => 'numeric'
                    ),
                    array( // Simple products type
                        'key'           => '_sale_price',
                        'value'         => 1000,
                        'compare'       => '<',
                        'type'          => 'numeric'
                    )
                )
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: By default, WooCommerce only stores the regular price and the sale price. It doesn't store the percent discount of the sale price. You will have to store that as it's own meta before you can query it. Perhaps there is some advanced SQL query that can compare the regular and sale price keys, but I'm not very good as SQL... and you'd still need to factor in sale dates of when an item is actually on sale.